# Continue execution asynchronously after return statement

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest

Is there any way to achieve this?

My actual requirement is, I want to return success from my rest service as soon I get the data and perform a basic action on it and then I want to continue some more operations on the data.

I thought of two approaches

1. Threading - Currently I don't know how I will make it through threading.
2. Bulk update - I will schedule a task that will do all this processing after may be an hour or so.

But I am not very sure how should I start implementing this.
Any help?

Comment: i don't quite get it. Are you talking from the point of view of a client? or you want to start an async process from your ajax call?

Comment: It seems that you should do something like a _service activator_.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of HTTP we have to remember that once we finish the response, the conversation is over.  There is really no way to keep the request alive after you have given the client a response.  You would need to implement some worker process that runs outside of HTTP that processes things "queued up" or "triggered" by an HTTP request.